# none of my images are showing up (not a server issue)

Tags: html, css

I've checked the coding within firebug and other inspectors and I can't figure it out. Sometimes, when I press refresh, the images for the first post will load, but the images for the subsequent posts are still not showing up.

I checked to see if there were any elements styled with `display:none` and I don't think this is the case either. I also disabled a plugin that could have been the case as well. For some reason, firefox (and safari on my iphone) are showing the `<p>`s but aren't displaying the images within the paragraphs.

It's very possible that this could be because of the recent CSS editing I've been doing over the past week, but I can't figure out what might have caused this issue.

http://www.brightontheday.com

here is the HTML for a sample image on the site:

```
 <img width="1" height="1" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.brightontheday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/2013-03-16-15.25.37.jpg?resize=550%2C806" alt="cobalt and pink" class="pinit size-full wp-image-12254" style="display: inline-block;" data-lazy-loaded="true">
```

Comment: Can you post code or a fiddle?

Comment: How do you know it's not a server issue? Please post some code and link to the images. -1 until you do, because we can't help you if you don't tell us these things

Comment: just realized i forgot to post the link!!! sorry! @doorknob

Comment: @Doorknob **-1 until you do** hahaha

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this type of question isn't terribly welcome on Stack Overflow for reasons outlined [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) - some code (or something else to work with independently from a mere link) is expected so the question can benefit future visitors. For what it's worth though, your site seems to be actively overriding the image sizes: `width=1 height=1` you'd have to look into why that happens.

Comment: No, post the code here.  That link will die in the future making this question meaningless.  This site exists to help others as much as the person asking the question.

Comment: @Mr.Alien ...? Why is that funny

Comment: @Doorknob That made me laugh.. simple

Comment: `width="1" height="1"` ***Really?!?!***

Comment: okkkk i see that now. be nice! something is causing that - because I sure didn't set it to be that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body .content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto \9;
}
```

must be

```
body .content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

in http://www.brightontheday.com/wp-content/themes/pagelines/pagelines-compiled-css-1_1368232018/ line 744.

Comment: I want to say thank you very much! this looks like I have a typo within my css and I can't thank you enough for catching this! AND for being nice - I'll be more prepared next time I bother anyone on here again. thanks again - so much!

Comment: If you `CTRL+F` -> `\9`, you will find 17 more errors such as `background-color: #d5d5d5 \9;`

Comment: @doorknob thank you so much. what on earth is that /9? how strange. maybe it's somewhere in my LESS and is coming through in the compiled css in several places?

Comment: The `\9` is not an error. It's the [IE9 backslash hack](http://webdood.com/?p=57)

Comment: oh, okay. that must be incorporated into my theme somewhere because I don't actually know that hack. strange that this is all coming up out of nowhere all of a sudden. @doorknob. but thank you for your help

Comment: oh, ok thanks @stephenmurdoch - is it strange that it's all of a sudden causing an error in firefox? It seems that hacks would be pointless if they only "fix" issues in IE (which SUCKS anyway) and then cause issues in other browsers

Comment: @doorknob ok that makes sense. but obviously that's not the case since it worked in my firefox....or was the reason for my width and height being overridden and set to 1px each. right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width and height of your images are set to 1..  You need to change this to a decent pixel size for your images to display as you require.

Comment: yes yes, I see that now. I'm very sorry I didn't see this before; I guess I was just panicking a little. But the things is, I didn't ever set that....know of anything that could automatically do that?

Comment: If the images showed up before you made changes, then you must have made something happen.

Comment: maybe something to do with display property?

Comment: You can edit the size of your images from in Wordpress.  Open up one of the posts in wp-admin and edit it, and see what size your images are within the editor.

Comment: this is the code within my editor view of wordpress: <code><img class="pinit size-full wp-image-12254" alt="cobalt and pink" src="http://www.brightontheday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/2013-03-16-15.25.37.jpg" width="550" height="806" /></code>